# Output error with parallel arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, runtime-error, output

```
for(i=0; i<NUM_STUDENTS; i++)
{

    if(studentGrades[i]>=GRADE_BOUNDS[0])
    {
        cout<<"Student "<<k<<" got "<<studentGrades[i]<<" which is a(n) "<<GRADE_LETTERS[0]<<endl;
    }

    else if(studentGrades[i]<GRADE_BOUNDS[10])
    {
        cout<<"Student "<<k<<" got "<<studentGrades[i]<<" which is a(n) "<<GRADE_LETTERS[11]<<endl;
    }

    for(j=0; j<GRADE_COUNT; j++)
    {
        if(studentGrades[i]<GRADE_BOUNDS[j]&&studentGrades[i]>=GRADE_BOUNDS[j+1])
        {
            cout<<"Student "<<k<<" got "<<studentGrades[i]<<" which is a(n) "<<GRADE_LETTERS[j+1]<<endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    k++;
}
```

Hi all, this is my first post on stackoverflow and I'll try to keep my question precise, I am currently in intro to programming so forgive me if my snippet is not top notch I am still learning. I am tasked with designing a program that will take user input of 20 student grades (0.0 - 100.0). The for loop that takes the input works fine, my current problem is that when I enter in a value that is less than 60 (which is considered an F in this case) the program will output "Student k got 59 which is a(n) F" twice in a row but when I enter in any value greater than 60 it works fine. Why is this happening? I will include my two array's that are being used in this snippet. The k++ at the end is just an accumulator variable to keep count of the students.

I originally had all three of the if statements inside the nested for loop, but my instructor suggested that I move the first two of them to the outside loop because the first two  if statements don't utilize the variable "j" at all so there is no need to have them inside the nested loop. It worked flawlessly until I made this change.

**Edited forgot to include GRADE_LETTERS array

```
const string GRADE_LETTERS[] = { "A", "A-", "B+",  "B", "B-", "C+", "C", "C-", "D+", "D", "D-", "F" };

const double GRADE_BOUNDS[] =  { 92.0, 90.0, 87.0, 82.0, 80.0, 77.0, 72.0, 70.0, 67.0, 62.0, 60.0, 0.0 };
const int GRADE_COUNT = sizeof( GRADE_BOUNDS ) / sizeof( GRADE_BOUNDS[0] );
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for putting the effort into posting code context and framing your question precisely - it really helps. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two places you can possibly print something:

```
    if(studentGrades[i]>=GRADE_BOUNDS[0]) // > 92.0
    else if(studentGrades[i]<GRADE_BOUNDS[10]) // < 60.0
```

and

```
    if(studentGrades[i]<GRADE_BOUNDS[j]&&studentGrades[i]>=GRADE_BOUNDS[j+1])
```

`GRADE_BOUNDS[0]` is 92.0, and if you enter a value above 92, it won't trigger the second condition. But the last entry in `GRADE_BOUNDS` is 0, so entering a value between 0 and 60 trigger both the top conditional (`else if(studentGrades[i] < 60)`) and the bottom conditional (`if(studentGrades[i]< 60 &&studentGrades[i]>= 0)`).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much that makes a lot of sense. It checks the condition of both if-then and then it would iterate the nested for loop which would not check for the upper bound of >= 92.0 but it would eventually check for 0=<i<60 again which is why I am getting a double output

Comment: Excellent! I approve of the way you rephrased the answer to help explain it to yourself. Good luck with your assignment! And don't worry about being a beginner -- we were all there once. Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 0):

get a segmentation fault if you have a grade which is You just forgot to continue to the next student once you found him in the first 2 if statements  :

```
if(studentGrades[i]>=GRADE_BOUNDS[0])
{
    cout<<"Student "<<i<<" got "<<studentGrades[i]<<" which is a(n) "<<GRADE_LETTERS[0]<<endl;
    continue;
 }        
 else if(studentGrades[i]<GRADE_BOUNDS[10])
 {
    cout<<"Student "<<i<<" got "<<studentGrades[i]<<" which is a(n) "<<GRADE_LETTERS[11]<<endl;
    continue;
 }
```

another problem will be the access to the `j+1` which will cause a buffer overflow (another segmentation fault)

Comment: I have not learned the continue keyword yet, I am guessing that if I were to use continue it would skip the nested for loop entirely and iterate the first for loop again? Noob question I know >.>

Comment: it will run the increment the counter and if it satisfies the condition it will enter the loop again (ends the current iteration).

Comment: Segmentation fault, unsure of what that entails but I don't believe I am accessing the -1 index anywhere in this snippet. I would agree that accessing j+1 would cause an overflow eventually but only if the grade was not in the bounds of 0.0-100.0, correct? The only way it could cause an overflow is if when searching through 0.0-100.0 the input is not found. It would try to search GRADE_BOUNDS[13] which does not exist. I guess I am unsure what you are trying to say here

Comment: you are right, i saw a j-1 instead of j+1, actually , you changed the code , you did have j-1...

Comment: I did have j-1 because before I posted my question I wanted to try a few other options just so I didn't look like a needy whiner or anything. I had tried to decrement j, set j=GRADE_COUNT and do j>0. But alas, it didn't work. I realized I had j-1, that is part of what edited